# How do make different messages pop up when different "difficulties" are choosen?

Tags: python, tkinter, drop-down-menu

I want different outcomes when different "difficulties" are choosen and I press start.
I can't make it work. I have tried to look for anwsers on youtube i didn't find anything helpful.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
import random

root = tk.Tk()

root.title("Simple Game")
canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width=300, height=300, bg="black")
canvas1.pack()
canvas1.create_text(150, 50, text="Simple Game", font="Times", fill="white")
root.resizable(False, False)

exitbutton = tk.Button(root, text="Exit Game", command=root.destroy, fg="black", activebackground="red").place(x=96,
                                                                                                               y=250)


def startgame():
    if DifficultyList == "Difficulty":
        messagebox.showinfo("Disclaimer", "You need to choose a difficulty!")
    elif DifficultyList == "Easy":
        messagebox.showinfo("Info", "You are now playing on Easy mode!")


startbutton = tk.Button(root, text="Start", command=startgame, fg="black", activeforeground="white",
                        activebackground="green").place(x=96, y=150)

canvas1.create_window(150, 150, window=exitbutton)
canvas1.create_window(150, 150, window=startbutton)

DifficultyList = (
    "Difficulty",
    "Easy",
    "Medium",
    "Hard"
)

variable = tk.StringVar(root)
variable.set(DifficultyList[0])

Difficulty = tk.OptionMenu(root, variable, *DifficultyList).place(x=94, y=100)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is the part I need help with. I need to make it understand that I refer to the options list.
def startgame(): 


if DifficultyList == "Difficulty":
        messagebox.showinfo("Disclaimer", "You need to choose a difficulty!")
    elif DifficultyList == "Easy":
        messagebox.showinfo("Info", "You are now playing on Easy mode!")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is part of basics of `tkinter`, you need to get the value from the variable/radiobutton, using `get()`, and check it with the value on the options list(`DifficultyList`), so your function would be like:

```py
def startgame():
    if variable.get() == DifficultyList[1]: # Check if 2nd item on list is selected
        messagebox.showinfo("Info", "You are now playing on Easy mode!")
    elif variable.get() == DifficultyList[2]:
        messagebox.showinfo("Info", "You are now playing on Medium mode!")
    elif variable.get() == DifficultyList[3]:
        messagebox.showinfo("Info", "You are now playing on Hard mode!")
    else: # If the selection is anything else other than above mentioned, then
        messagebox.showinfo("Disclaimer", "You need to choose a difficulty!")
```

Notice how I changed your `if` and moved it to `else`, because it is the only statement left to choose from the list, hence it is part of `else`. Yes, you can choose any other one statement to be `else` too, but this is the only odd one out, so I chose this.

---

Note that while naming variables to follow a convention, like a list would be usually named in all small letters, but class would be named following [PascalCase](https://techterms.com/definition/pascalcase#:%7E:text=PascalCase%20is%20a%20naming%20convention,in%20PascalCase%20is%20always%20capitalized.) and function might be named using [camelCase](https://techterms.com/definition/camelcase) but usual variables are all small letters. Also check: [Some common naming conventions are for python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Python_and_Ruby)

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I couldn't find any tutorials that helped me with this problem, but it works as I want it to now :)